# Should I be worried that the company I was recently hired for posted a job advert similar to my position?

Tags: job-offer, new-job

Last week I accepted a job offer to start working next week. I submitted the contracts as well as the usual HR requirements + an online consent for background check.

Today I see a new job advert for the same position I was just hired for. I don't have any criminal records so I doubt they found anything suspicious in my background check.

What can be the reasons they are posting a similar job? Should I be worried? Is it rational to expect to be laid off before even starting?

Answer (score 14):

Back in the day, when I interviewed for a job, I always asked if they were expanding or replacing an old person. Depending on how big they are, they could just need a new [whatever you are] every month or so. I know firms planning to hire 50 people in a specific role over a year - that's one a week!

They would never lay you off then immediately try to hire someone: laying off is because there isn't work for you. They might cancel your offer, but then they would, you know, **cancel your offer** by letting you know. The chances are overwhelming they're just hiring more and more people. Usually a good sign.

Anyway, since you're scheduled to start next week, you'll know soon enough what's up.

Answer (score 10):

> What can be the reasons they are posting a similar job?

There can be many possible reasons. They might be hiring for another additional role similar to yours. Or the ad might have be scheduled to go out before your formal acceptance and couldn't be canceled in time.

> Should I be worried?

I always take the approach that you shouldn't be worried until you actually know you have something to worry about.

> Is it rational to expect to be laid off before even starting?

There's no benefit to worrying about that now. Try to be patient. One way or the other, you'll know soon enough.